# How to make cells visible based on defined condition in FPDF PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

Actually I am new in PDF generation in PHP. 
I have a PDF page and in that page I have a field named "paid type" which includes ("cash","cheque","credit"). I want it when I choose cash only and the cash amount is displayed. If 2 currency types were chosen I want to display the currencies too by omitting the credit amount which is zero.
Since my page is static I have hard coded the form. Even when the cash is chosen the credit card amount is displayed with value zero.
Can someone help me out please?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: //last row
$pdf->Cell( 0.75, 0.3, '', 0, 0, 'C', true );
$pdf->Cell( 2.5, 0.3, "Credit Card Amount :", 0, 0, 'C', true );
$pdf->Cell( 1.3, 0.3, $credit_amount , 0, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 0.5, 0.3, "", 0, 0, 'C', true );
$pdf->Cell( 0.5, 0.3, "", 0, 0, 'C', true );
$pdf->Cell( 1.3, 0.3, "", 0, 0, 'C', true );
$pdf->Cell( 1.3, 0.3, "Total :", 'LB', 0, 'R', true );
$pdf->Cell( 0.9, 0.3, $currency, 'B', 0, 'R', true );
$pdf->Cell( 1.3, 0.3, $total_price, 'RB', 1, 'C', true );

Comment: as you can see for this row when the .$credit_amount is zero I do not want the "Credit card Amount " to be displayed.